# LabelEncoder - reverse and use categorical data on model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, label, encoder

I am working on a prediction project (for fun) and basically I pulled male and female names from nltk, label names as 'male' or 'female', then get the last letter of each name, and in the end use different machine learning algorithms to train and predict gender based on last letter.

So we know that Python's sklearn does NOT handle categorical data, so I used LabelEncoder to transform last letter to numeric values:

Before transform:

```
     name     last_letter    gender
0    Aamir    r              male
1    Aaron    n              male
2    Abbey    y              male
3    Abbie    e              male
4    Abbot    t              male

     name       last_letter    gender
0    Abagael    l              female
1    Abagail    l              female
2    Abbe       e              female
3    Abbey      y              female
4    Abbi       i              female
```

And if we concatenate two dataframes, drop the name column and shuffle:

```
     last_letter    gender
0    a              male
1    e              female
2    g              male
3    h              male
4    e              male
```

Then I used `LabelEncoder`:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()

for col in df.columns:
    df[col]= label_encoder.fit_transform(df[col])
df.head()
```

The dataframe becomes:

```
     last_letter    gender
0    1              male
1    5              female
2    7              male
3    8              male
4    5              male
```

As you can see, after training the model (let's say Random Forest here). If I want to use the model to predict a random letter

```
e.g. rf_model.predict('a')
```

It's not gonna work since the model only takes numeric values. In this case if I do:

```
rf_model.predict(1) (assume letter 'a' is encoded as number 1)
```

The model prediction result returns

```
array([1])
```

So how do I do something like:

```
rf_model.predict('a')
```

and get a result like 'female' or 'male' instead of having to enter a numeric value and get a result as numeric value?

Comment: Use pipeline to concatenate the labelEncoder with the estimator (random forest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the same `LabelEncoder` you created! Since you already `fit` it with the training data, you can directly apply new data with `transform` function.

```
In [2]: from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

In [3]: label_encoder = LabelEncoder()

In [4]: label_encoder.fit_transform(['a', 'b', 'c'])
Out[4]: array([0, 1, 2])

In [5]: label_encoder.transform(['a'])
Out[5]: array([0])
```

To use it with `RandomForestClassifier`,

```
In [59]: from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

In [60]: X = ['a', 'b', 'c']

In [61]: y = ['male', 'female', 'female']

In [62]: X_encoded = label_encoder.fit_transform(X)

In [63]: rf_model = RandomForestClassifier()

In [64]: rf_model.fit(X_encoded[:, None], y)
Out[64]: 
RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
            max_depth=None, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
            min_impurity_split=1e-07, min_samples_leaf=1,
            min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
            n_estimators=10, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False, random_state=None,
            verbose=0, warm_start=False)

In [65]: x = ['a']

In [66]: x_encoded = label_encoder.transform(x)

In [67]: rf_model.predict(x_encoded[:, None])
Out[67]: 
array(['male'], 
      dtype='<U6')
```

As you can see, you can get string output `'male', 'female'` directly from classifier if you used them to fit the classifier.

Refer to [`LabelEncoder.transform`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.transform)